# Automated docker builds with private bitbucket server

Tags: docker, bitbucket-server

I was looking to setup automated docker builds when a push is made to our bitbucket server. The only issue is that our Bitbucket is not cloud based, its an on premise private server. Is there a way to configure automated builds for the docker hub when a push is made to our private server? Obviously Docker can't see our private server, but is there a way to accomplish the same thing using web hooks in the private bitbucket repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Packer template](https://www.packer.io/), specifically with a [Docker builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html) to do this. Triggering this build can be done with hooks (either BitBucket webhooks, or [git server post-receive hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Building a Docker image from a Packer template has some benefits, but requires [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) installed - so, doing the build with a Dockerfile would also be an option.

The tricky part would be the management of credentials. Building the image does not require credentials, nor does tagging -- however you need to be authenticated to push the image to the registry. If the build happens on the same server that is hosting BitBucket, you could keep them in a protected file and execute the build via the post-receive hook in a shell script. This would be a lightweight option, especially if the server itself is locked down.

So, in summary :

1. Install Docker Engine on the BitBucket Server
2. Write a script which can consume registry username and password, to build the image, either from a Dockerfile or from a Packer template.
3. Add a server-side git hook to execute this script to build, tag and push the image.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will look into leveraging Packer. I understand the process though as you described and I believe it makes sense for my scenario.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) We typically follow the pattern of having a .pipeline directory, with all of the things necessary for shipping the product- a .travis.yml, a Dockerfile, Packer template, etc. This keeps the code of the app clean, and yet keeps all the configuration for deployment in the same repo. Hope this helps.